# Is the Crimean Bridge in danger of collapsing?

Tags: bridges

Some sources point to difficulties which may destroy the bridge, so the Wikipedia article on the Crimean Bridge e.g. has:

"The geology of the Kerch Strait is difficult: it has a tectonic fault, and the bedrock is covered by a 60 m (197 ft) layer of silt.[44] About 70 mud volcanoes have been found in the area of the strait.[44] More than 7,000 piles support the bridges; these piles have been driven up to 91 m (300 ft) beneath the water surface.[44] Some of the piles are at an angle to make the structure more stable during earthquakes.[44]

Some experts have expressed doubts that the construction is durable, given the tectonic and sea current conditions in the strait.[44][45]

44. Pollock, Emily (6 July 2018), [Europe’s Longest Bridge Spans Troubled Waters](http://web.archive.org/web/20181013090024/https://www.engineering.com/BIM/ArticleID/17007/Europes-Longest-Bridge-Spans-Troubled-Waters.aspx), Engineering.com, archived from the original on 13 October 2018
45. [Kerch Strait Bridge may collapse at any time – expert](https://economics.unian.info/10296951-kerch-strait-bridge-may-collapse-at-any-time-expert.html), UNIAN, 12 October 2018

Comment: So, what do you think is wrong with the experts' opinions?

Comment: @Solar Mike I am asking a question, and have not said that I think there is something wrong with some expert's opinions. There does not seem to be a consensus among experts.

Comment: So, for an answer : "Yes, there is always a risk"...

Comment: Yes. It would be interesting to have a probability estimate, or something like that.

Comment: So, what events would you include in the probability calculations?

Comment: Events connected with the geological conditions in the seabed.

Comment: So ignoring Froude number and other interesting phenomena...

Comment: @SolarMike I am not an expert in these matters, and so merely ask for  advice from others who are. It would be interesting to me if you or others could weigh in some on the topic, as it concerns an intriguing bridge.

Comment: Considering the military activity in the area, the bridge is definitely in danger of collapsing, due to demolishing it as a very important strategical object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluating safety and risks involved in a project of this magnitude and complexity need a multifaceted scientific research, composed of teams representing different areas of technology, with experts to sample the soils, water current; chemical engineers, meteorologist, seismologists, etc, expensive imaging, testing machinery. It could cost millions of dollars and many years.

I had two classmates in college many years ago who spent their entire Ph.D. time doing an assessment of the safety of a small single span 110-foot bridge in Massachusets, with unlimited help from undergrad students at the lab.

Your question is way too ambitious for a site like this.

Comment: FYI, I really don't like when people use "forum" to describe the main Stackexchange sites.  We are not a forum, we are a question and answer site.  In a forum, discussion of something like this may still be possible, and likely well within the scope of what the site wants to accomplish.  In a Q&A site, this is well outside of the scope of questions that should be answered, and this isn't really somewhere to just discuss things without finding answers.

Comment: @JMac, it was corrected.

Comment: I see there is an initiative to close my question. What would be a good place to discuss this topic?